# Calculate mean in dt

Tags: r, data.table

I got a pivottable that appears in my console that has names and years

So the first thing I want to do is that I want to remove all rows (in this case row C) that have a sum of zero using datatables.
I modified this code, that worked perfectly out on my datatable

```
dt[apply(dt, 1, function(x) min(x) != max(x)), ]
```

to this code to get what I want but that did not work.

```
dt[apply(dt, 1, function(x) sum(x) = 0, ]
```

The second question I have is that I want to calculate the mean of all those rows without taking the zeros into account.

Does anyone know the right code for these two questions?

Comment: I think you may have intended to use the `!=` operator.  Try this: `dt[apply(dt, 1, function(x) sum(x) != 0, ]`

Comment: (i) Your zeros should not be zeros but `NA` values because you want to treat them as such. `mean` can handle `NA` values in exactly the way you want. (ii) Never use `apply` in data.table, it's even worse then using the `by` parameter with a row index. (iii) Logical comparison is `==` and not `=`. (iv) I advise to reshape to a long format data.table.

Comment: You can always do `mean(x[x != 0])` to take the mean except for the 0s. But Roland has good points. For this, the better way to do it would probably be to tidy your data into a long format with `melt` and then use group means with `by`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
# remove row with zeros
df <- df[apply(df[,-1],1, function(x)sum(x) != 0),]

# calculate mean without zeros
df$new_col  <- apply(df[,-1],1, function(x) mean(x[x!=0]))

print(df)

      random X2000 X2001 X2002 X2003 X2004 X2005 new_col
1      A     1     0     2     1     4     5     2.60
2      B     1     1     0     1     1     1     1.00
4      D     2     2     2     2     2     2     2.00
5      E     2     3     0     0     1     1     1.75
6      F     0     1     1     0     0     0     1.00
7      G     3     3     3     3     3     3     3.00
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `rowSums` to remove the rows that have all 0s and then use `rowMeans` by converting the 0's to `NA` and with `na.rm = TRUE` get the `mean` for each row

```
i1 <-  rowSums(!!df1[-1]) != 0
df1 <- df1[i1,]
df1$new_col <- rowMeans(df1[-1]*NA^(!df1[-1]), na.rm = TRUE)
df1$new_col
#[1] 2.60 1.00 2.00 1.75 1.00 3.00
```